# (Python 3) Classification of dataset, using a user input Elo, to suggest opening move based on Chess dataset?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, artificial-intelligence, naivebayes

I'm just looking for a little bit of help. I'm struggling to work out if what I'm doing is right or not, and even if Naive Bayes is even the right way to do this.

I am wanting the user to be able to input their elo, and the 'app' to suggest them a opening move set, based on win rate at that ELO. For this I am using the following dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/datasnaek/chess

The important data out of this, are the opening name (what I'm trying to suggest), the average rating (what the user can input), and winner (we need to see if white wins).

This is my code so far:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from sklearn import preprocessing
#Import Gaussian Naive Bayes model
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB


#Read in dataset
data = pd.read_csv(f"games.csv")

# set new column that is true/false depending on if white wins
data['white_wins'] = (data['winner'] == "white")


# Create new columns, average rating (based on white rating and black rating) and category (categorization of rating for Naive Bayes)
data['average_rating'] = data.apply(lambda row: (row['white_rating'] + row['black_rating']) / 2, axis=1)
data['category'] = data['average_rating'] // 100 + 1

# Drop unneccessary columns
data = data.drop(['turns', 'moves', 'victory_status', 'id', 'winner', 'rated', 'created_at', 'last_move_at', 'opening_ply', 'white_id', 'black_id', 'increment_code', 'opening_eco', 'white_rating', 'black_rating'], axis=1)

#Label Encoder Initialisation
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()


# Converting string labels into numbers.
opening_name_encoded=le.fit_transform(data.opening_name)
category_encoded=le.fit_transform(data.category)
label=le.fit_transform(data.white_wins)

#Package features together
features=zip(opening_name_encoded, category_encoded)


#Create a Gaussian Classifier
model = GaussianNB()


# Train the model using the training sets
model.fit(features,label)
```

And i currently get the error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccxbF.png)

Also, i'm not even convinced this is correct, as if i continue down this stream, I am only going to be predicting if white wins based on the opening moveset, and elo. I'm really unsure on where to take this to get it to the point i need.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

`zip` returns in iterator, so your code is not doing what you expect. My guess is that you intended `features` to be a list of 2-tuples. If that is the case, then adjust your code to `features = list(zip(opening_name_encoded, category_encoded))`

```
In [31]: zip([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'])
Out[31]: <zip at 0x25d61abfd80>

In [32]: list(zip([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']))
Out[32]: [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
```